# Autohotkey continuous macro

Tags: macros, autohotkey

since I have to give away my macro keyboard I found autohotkey to be reliable. Sadly I didn't really find out how to make continuous macros..

what I mean is: (pseudo code)

```
^!c:: 
while ^!c is not pressed again -> send keystrokes c
```

spamm infinite c keystrokes until I press the combination above again

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

```
 toggle = 0   ; timer is off because toggle isn't yet initialized
 return

 ^!c::        ; toggle timer
 if toggle := !toggle       
   SetTimer, Send_c, 0    
 else 
   SetTimer, Send_c, off 
 return

  Send_c:
 Send c
 Sleep, 300
 return
```